# show application error when build application s40 5th edition using netbeans

Tags: eclipse, java-me, lwuit

I am trying to use LWUIT in my application, and I am using Eclipse IDE. I did one sample application. When I run the application I got the "Application error" (i.e) No class def found error java/lang/noclassdefFounerror com/sun/lwuit/events/Actionlistionr

Comment: In the title you mentioned NetBeans IDE, But In the description you mentioned Eclipse IDE. Which IDE you are using?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse MTJ on the build properties of the project choose export for the jar file where your lwuit classes come from.